# How many independent unbounded derivations exists in $C^{\infty}[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C^{\infty}[0,1]$ be the space of smooth function defined on $[0,1]$. We know that any smooth function times differential operator is a unbounded derivation. Can we construct more than that? For example,  let $P$ be space of polynomials and $D$ a derivation on $C^{\infty}[0,1]$, we define $D(x)=1$ and $D(f)=0$ for $f\in C^{\infty}[0,1]\backslash P$. Is $D$ a unbounded derivation? If the  example works, can we conclude there are infinitely many unbounded derivation on $C^{\infty}[0,1]$?

Comment: Looks like $D$ so defined is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials are dense in $C^{\infty}[0,1]$, so take a non constant $f\in C^{\infty}[0,1]\backslash P$ and let $p_n\to f$. Then $D(p_n)\to f' \neq 0$ but $D(f)=0$. Therefore the operator is not continuous.

Comment: What if we allow $D$ is unbounded,i.e discontinuous?

Comment: From what I wrote, it has to be discontinuous. What other derivations are you looking for? The usual derivative is unbounded, and you propose another operator that is the same on a subspace (the polynomials), and $0$ everywhere else. You can do that with any subspace of $C^\infty$. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, I originally thought such kind of derivation is not well defined, but it seems not.